# Is heapq in Python thread safe?

Tags: python, thread-safety

I need multiple threads to access this heapq. So I want to make sure to conduct such operations using heapq.

Comment: You will have to do the locking, as @martijn-pieters put it - but you might as well use a PriorityQueue instead of re-wiring heapq. https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, using the `heapq` library is not threadsafe. Use a lock to coordinate access.

Note that the [library documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html) links to the [source code](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/heapq.py); you can always take a look yourself to see how it behaves. You'll see that the module operates on a regular Python `list` and there is no locking code.

If all you want is a priority queue, then look no further than the [`Queue.PriorityQueue()` class](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html#Queue.PriorityQueue) (renamed to [`queue.PriorityQueue`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#queue.PriorityQueue) in Python 3). It is fully thread-safe.